# C++ Split String Every X Characters

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

I am trying to write a function that takes a string, and splits every X number of characters:

```
std::vector<std::string> DIFSplitStringByNumber(std::string s, int l)
{
    const char *c = s.c_str();  
    char buffer[l];
    std::vector<std::string> entries;
    entries.reserve(int(s.length() / l) + 1);

    int d = 0;   
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1;)
    {
        if(d != l)
        {
            buffer[d] = c[i];
            d++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            entries.push_back(std::string(buffer, l));

            //Clear array
            memset(buffer, 0, l);
            d = 0;
        }       
    }

    return entries;
}
```

For example, If I called `DIFSplitStringByNumber("hello!", 2)`, I should get a vector containing:

```
[0] he
[1] ll
[2] o!
```

However, it only seems to get the first two results (the vector size is 2), and when I do something like `DIFSplitStringByNumber("hello", 2)`, it crashes, presumably because its trying to access an array index that doesn't exist (it expects 6 characters, but there are only 5). Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Why no string::substr ?

Comment: Are VLAs (such as `char buffer[l]`) allowed in C++?

Comment: @barakmanos In C++14 or with g++, yes

Comment: @barakmanos I didn't even realize that was a nonstandard construction. I suppose it should've been something like ``char *buffer = new char[l]``?

Comment: @Igor: Yes, that's what I would use... But if it's working for you, well, what can I say :) ... In any case, I wrote an answer (below), suggesting how you should calculate the size of your vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will split a string into a vector. If there aren't an even number of splits, it will add the extra characters to the end.

```
std::vector<std::string> Split(const std::string& str, int splitLength)
{
   int NumSubstrings = str.length() / splitLength;
   std::vector<std::string> ret;

   for (auto i = 0; i < NumSubstrings; i++)
   {
        ret.push_back(str.substr(i * splitLength, splitLength));
   }

   // If there are leftover characters, create a shorter item at the end.
   if (str.length() % splitLength != 0)
   {
        ret.push_back(str.substr(splitLength * NumSubstrings));
   }


   return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The heart of the algorithm really comes down to the following two lines.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i += l)
    res.push_back(s.substr(i, l));
```

Also, you should pass the string by const reference.

Comment: It works, but doesn't seem to be as fast as millsj's solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using that std::string is a collection of char, a simple implementation could be :

```
std::vector<std::string> DIFSplitStringByNumber(const std::string & str, int len)
{
    std::vector<std::string> entries;
    for(std::string::const_iterator it(str.begin()); it != str.end();)
    {
        int nbChar = std::min(len,(int)std::distance(it,str.end()));
        entries.push_back(std::string(it,it+nbChar));
        it=it+nbChar;
    };
    return entries;
}
```

[Live sample](https://ideone.com/1gLBKb)

Answer (score 2):

Change the way that you are calculating the vector size:

```
int size = (s.length() - 1) / l + 1;
```

This is equivalent to the ceiling of the input string length divided by the input length.

BTW, the `int(s.length() / l)` casting is useless, since both operands are integers.

---

Finally, use this size inside the loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
```