# Split character array into multiple parts

Tags: arrays, c

In C, how would I go about splitting a char array into multiple parts, then back into an array.  I am looking to split into 10 parts.  But to make sure when it's split, it's split at a space and not by the character count.

I would like to be able to split it into another array so I can just call the index for each of them.  But I am rather new to C/C++.  In Java, I assume I could create an Array and then call array[0]-array[9] to get the split values after the operation is complete.

I would have:

`char *s1 = "An example array that can be present right here.  With a lot more words than this. But this is just an example after all.  So does it really matter currently?"`

And would need to be split into 10 parts (doesn't need to be equal in length) but just in 10 semi-equal parts.

Comment: Checkout the [`strchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) function

Comment: Beware: you cannot modify a string literal such as you show.  More precisely, modifying a string literal results in undefined behaviour, but the usual consequence is a crash as your code attempts to modify read-only memory.

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022880/c-split-string-every-x-characters

Comment: I see what you want - you want to split at the space that is closest to 1/10th the length of the string, storing the pieces in a separate array so that they are NULL terminated without modifying the original string (because it might be a string literal).

Answer (score 0):

So there are two parts to this:

1. a function that can find the closest space character to the next split point
2. a function that finds the next wrap point and saves the resulting string

For the first function, we need to pass in the string, its size, the last wrap point, and the next potential wrap point.  It needs to return the next actual wrap point.  So the function will have a definition like this:

```
int wrappoint(const char *string, int size, int previous, int current);
```

To find the next wrap point we need to search for a space character from the current wrap point both forward (until the end of the string) and backward (until the previous wrap point):

```
    int before=-1, after=-1;
    for(int i=current; i>previous; i--)
        if(string[i] == ' ')
            { before = i; break; }
    for(int i=current; i<=size; i++)
        if(string[i] == ' ')
            { after = i; break; }
```

At this point `before` and `after` will contain the indices of the nearest space characters - or -1 if a space was not found i nthat direction.  Then we just need to return a valid next wrap point based on what we found:

```
    if(before==-1 && after==-1)
        return size;
    else if(before==-1)
        return after;
    else if(after==-1)
        return before;
    else if(current-before < after-current)
        return before;
    else
        return after;
```

For the second function, we can just pass the string and the number of parts.  The function will dynamically allocate an array big enough to hold all the parts.  Each array index will be a pointer to a dynamically allocated string.  Then the function can return the array and it will be the caller's responsibility to free all that memory.  So the function will have a definition like this:

```
char **split(const char *string, int parts) {
```

The first thing we need to do is find the length of the string and make an array to hold all the parts.  We use `calloc` so that any indices we don't use will be set to `NULL`:

```
    char **array = calloc(parts, sizeof(char *));
    int size = strlen(string);
```

Then we have to loop through the string, calling the `wrappoint` function to find the start and end of each part, allocating space for that part and then copying that part into the array:

```
    int previous = 0, current = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < parts && current < size; i++) {
        current = wrappoint(string, size, previous, previous+size/parts);
        array[i] = malloc(current-previous+1);
        strncpy(array[i], string+previous, current-previous);
        array[i][current-previous] = '\0';
        previous = current+1;
    }
```

Then we can call `split`, which returns an array containing the parts - but some of them might be `NULL` if there are fewer spaces in the string than the number of parts we asked for.  We can display the array of parts like this:

```
    for(int i=0; i<10 && array[i]; i++)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, array[i]);
```

And then when we are done we have to free all the memory that `split` allocated:

```
    for(int i=0; i<10 && array[i]; i++)
        free(array[i]);
    free(array);
```

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int wrappoint(const char *string, int size, int previous, int current) {
    int before=-1, after=-1;
    for(int i=current; i>previous; i--)
        if(string[i] == ' ')
            { before = i; break; }
    for(int i=current; i<=size; i++)
        if(string[i] == ' ')
            { after = i; break; }

    if(before==-1 && after==-1)
        return size;
    else if(before==-1)
        return after;
    else if(after==-1)
        return before;
    else if(current-before < after-current)
        return before;
    else
        return after;
}

char **split(const char *string, int parts) {
    char **array = calloc(parts, sizeof(char *));
    int size = strlen(string);
    int previous = 0, current = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < parts && current < size; i++) {
        current = wrappoint(string, size, previous, previous+size/parts);
        array[i] = malloc(current-previous+1);
        strncpy(array[i], string+previous, current-previous);
        array[i][current-previous] = '\0';
        previous = current+1;
    }
    return array;
}

int main() {
    char *string = "An example array that can be present right here.  With a lot more words than this. But this is just an example after all.  So does it really matter currently?";
    char **array = split(string,10);

    for(int i=0; i<10 && array[i]; i++)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, array[i]);

    for(int i=0; i<10 && array[i]; i++)
        free(array[i]);
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it at https://onlinegdb.com/uoDzM2toi

This example string:

> An example array that can be present right here.  With a lot more words than this. But this is just an example after all.  So does it really matter currently?

Produces this output:

```
0: An example array
1: that can be present
2: right here.  With
3: a lot more words
4: than this. But
5: this is just an
6: example after
7: all.  So does it
8: really matter
9: currently?
```